# AVFoundation: Lag when segueing into a camera view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera, avfoundation

I have a successfully implemented a QRCode scanner into my app, everything is working well and with good performance. However, at my app's home screen, when you press the button to segue to the actual view controller doing the scanning, there is at least a 750ms/1 sec lag.

Here is the camera setup:

```
- (void)setupCaptureSession { // 1
    if (_captureSession) return;
    // 2
    _videoDevice = [self frontCamera];//[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (!_videoDevice) {
        DDLogWarn(@"No video camera on this device!"); return;
    }
    // 3
    _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    // 4
    _videoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:_videoDevice error:nil];
    // 5
    if ([_captureSession canAddInput:_videoInput]) { [_captureSession addInput:_videoInput];
    }
    // 6
    _previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
    _previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    _metadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];

    //dispatch_queue_t metadataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("org.iso.QRCode.metadata", 0);
    dispatch_queue_t metadataQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    [_metadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:metadataQueue];
    if ([_captureSession canAddOutput:_metadataOutput]) {
        //DDLogNotice(@"WE ARE OUTPUTING METADATA!");
        [_captureSession addOutput:_metadataOutput];
        _metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode];
    }
//    [self startRunning];
}
```

This method is being fired in `viewDidLoad` and in `viewWillAppear` fire `[self startRunning]` (which just starts the camera session.

The biggest offender here looks like `dispatch_queue_t metadataQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();` is it that when I fire the segue from the previous view controller, the main thread is being blocked to start the camera, and blocking the UI momentarily? Would it be best to setup the camera in a different thread?

**EDIT**
I moved `[self startRunning]` to `viewDidAppear` and this helped the segue lag tremendously, however it takes a good second before the camera preview will load. Are there any elegant ways to decrease the camera live preview time?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am also facing the same lag.

Comment: @KunalShrivastava So far I am using exactly the same code, and in viewDidAppear doing [self startRunning]. Performance seems to be excellent, let me know if you have any more issues and we can try to work through it!

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. Thanks so much.